# django create client user

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I try to call create a client user so i have toc call create_client method from the client model to create a client user, I can create superuser but I don't know how to create client user I really don't understand how it works if someone can explain to me and I will be thankful

view.py :

```
def signup(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

form.py

```
class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password.
    """
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email','full_name')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserAdminChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email','full_name','password', 'active', 'admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]

class Form(forms.Form):
    fullname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placedholder': 'you full name !'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'your email'}))
    content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': ' content! '}))

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if not 'email.com' in email:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Email has to be gmail ')
        return email

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
        """
        A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
        fields, plus a repeated password.
        """
        password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
        password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('email', 'full_name')

        def clean_password2(self):
            # Check that the two password entries match
            password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
            password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
            if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
            return password2

        def save(self, commit=True):
            # Save the provided password in hashed format
            user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
            user.active = True
            user.client = True
            if commit:
                user.save()
            return user
```

models.py

```
class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,email,full_name=None,password=None , is_active=True,is_staff=False,is_admin=False,is_client=False):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an password ')

        user_object = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            full_name=full_name,

        )

        user_object.set_password(password)
        user_object.staff =is_staff
        user_object.admin = is_admin
        user_object.active = is_active
        user_object.client = is_client

        user_object.save(using=self._db)
        return user_object

    def create_Client(self, email, e, password, full_name=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            full_name=full_name,
            password=password,
            is_client=True
        )

    def create_staffuser(self, email,e, password,full_name=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            full_name =full_name,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True
        )

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password,full_name=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            full_name = full_name,
            password=password,
            is_staff = True,
            is_admin = True,
        )

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class Account(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True,null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # a admin user; non super-user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # a superuser
    client = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # a superuser

    # notice the absence of a "Password field", that is built in.

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []


    objects = AccountManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        if self.full_name:
            return self.full_name
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True
    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.email

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        "Is the user a admin member?"
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        "Is the user active?"
        return self.active

    @property
    def is_client(self):
        "Is the user active?"
        return self.client
```